# "Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: /

Tags: mysql

> va"Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded:
>   /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so: cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or directory"

i got this error when i try to connect to mysql from emma or mysql bench on ubuntu 18.04

There is similar issue but it is for windows

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49963383/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password

i tried to reinstall and this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50027851/9658011

but did not work.

What can i do?

[image: emma]

Answer (score 3):

Use this query:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'YourPassword';
```

You don't get `caching_sha2_password`.
Then connect to MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I solved. I installed mysql 5.7 on 18.04, not latest version.

```
738  sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-core- mysql-client-core-
  739  sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql
  740  sudo apt-get autoremove
  741  sudo apt-get autoclean
  742  sudo apt install mysql-client-5.7
  743  sudo apt install mysql-common-5.7
  744  sudo apt install mysql-common
  745  sudo apt install mysql-common-5.7
  746  sudo apt install mysql-client-5.7
  747  systemctl status mysql.service
  748  sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe'
  749  sudo apt install mysql-client-5.7
  750  sudo apt install mysql-server-5.7
  751  sudo apt install mysql-common-5.8
  752  sudo apt-get purge mysql-client-core-5.6
  753  sudo apt-get autoremove
  754  sudo apt-get autoclean
  755  sudo apt install mysql-client-core-5.5
```

None of previos worked. So i did those and worked:

```
  756  sudo apt install mysql-client-core-5.6
  757  sudo apt install mysql-server  
  758  mysql_secure_installation
  759  mysql -u root -p
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest MYSQL versions have 'caching_sha2_password' as the default authentication type. Which does not allow remote connections to MYSQL and results in caching_sha2_password plugin error.
I have fixed it using

> ALTER USER 'yourusername'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH
> mysql_native_password BY 'youpassword';

Now it allows your user to access MySQL from localhost.

If you want to access MySQL from multiple remote hosts then do the following,

> ALTER USER 'yourusername'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY
> 'youpassword';

After every alter command in SQL run the following to take effect.

> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

OR restart MySQL server

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS, install library **caching_sha2_password.so** using:

```
apt-get install libmariadb3
```

Comment: How did you install caching_sha2_password.so?

Answer (score -1):

I used

```
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

mode method, so instead I tend to retain this installation *as is, intact*.